# How to get a particular column value by using Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-migrations

I have two migration tables and two models

1)User.
2)Subscription.

in subscriptions Model i write one method called user() which has `hasMany` relationship and in Users model it will contain subscriptions() method which have `belongs()` relationship.

in user table id acts as an primary key and in subscription table sub_id acts as a foriegn key,for example if the user subscribed to any subscription the user id will store in the sub_id in the subscription table upto this it's working fine.

```
 $is_subscription=Subscription::where('sub_id',$user->id)->value('sub_id');
```

from the above code i am able to get the value but now what i want is is there any better way to write the query based on models ,please help me to write this one..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to check whether an user has any subscription?

Comment: @KevinBui, yes I am trying for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your descriptions, I believe this is what you have:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
    }
}

class Subscription extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

So you want to check whether an user has any subscriptions. You can do one of the followings:

```php
$user->subscriptions()->exists();

// Or

$user->subscriptions->isNotEmpty();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$is_subscription=Subscription::where('sub_id',$user->id)->pluck('sub_id');
```

You can find details on the methods that are available for collection using the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

Comment: is there any way to use Eloquent ORM concept i am very new to the laravel @Romantic Dev

Comment: Actually, It is already an Eloquent ORM query. Tell us what you want to do in detail.

Comment: actually what i need is getting data one related model from other model

Comment: in my user model i have like this :->public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
    }

Comment: based on this methods is there any other way to get the data

Comment: Try this query:  $is_subscription=Subscription::where('sub_id', $id)->with('users')->pluck('sub_id');

Comment: is there any way in model function can return id to this query  $is_subscription=Subscription::where('sub_id', $id)->with('users')->pluck('sub_id');

Comment: If you want to get a single ID against single record, then try first() function instead of pluck('sub_id')

Comment: $is_subscription=Subscription::where('sub_id', $id)->with('users')->first();

$is_subscription->id;

Comment: $ss=User::subscriptions()->where('psub_id',$item->id)->first(); i am trying like this but it's showing call to undefined

Comment: Use whereHas. $ss = User::whereHas('subscriptions', function (Builder $query) {
 $query->where('psub_id', $item->id);
 })
 ->first();